# Windows Media Player lists every track as its own album

Tags: windows-media-player

I am generally a fan of WMP but I copied an MP3 album from my other PC and every track is listed as an identical 1-track album. It's the sound-track to The Matrix and I wonder if the fact each track is a different artist is to blame?

I can't see any ways to manually change this, do they exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to change the album artist to "Various." Or if that isn't an option just change the artist to various... either way they should end up as the same album.